# How can I install 64 bit mongodb after installing 32 bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, mongodb

I recently installed mongodb for a project for a data mining class I'm taking and while loading all the documents I needed I got an error specifying `mongodb is out of memory` and that I needed to install the 64 bit version to add additional records to the database.

Problem is, I don't know how to do that (or uninstall the 32 bit version..).

Comment: How did you install -- with apt-get & friends?

Comment: Yup, apt-get for sure.

Comment: ok, next silly question :)  you are running a 64-bit linux distro, right?

Comment: yeah i have the 32-bit version, just double checked

Answer (score 1):

Based on a little poking around and [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/0BjJgKodYaU/discussion), I *think* `apt-get install mongodb` or `mongodb-10gen` will "just work" and install a 32-bit mongo server on a 32-bit linux distro, or a 64-bit mongo server on a 64-bit distro.

Which do you have?  Try this:

```
$ arch
x86_64
```

That tells me I'm running 64-bit linux.  So I can choose to run either 32-bit mongo or 64-bit mongo.  If there were a "32" in there, I'd be running a 32-bit linux distro, and could only run 32-bit mongo atop it.

Now, take all this with a grain of salt, as I personally use `apt-get` for practically everything *except* mongodb, which I manage several versions of concurrently.

So, I find it simpler and more predictable to just go to the [10gen distributions page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads), and download and untar the version I want.  After that, executing the right `bin/mongod` just works right out of the box.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey thanks! i'll try and untar the other mongo distro, i used apt-get so it got the 32 bit version since i have an i686 (32 bit os though) machine. hopefully it works out, i have 9+ million records in this database that i want to use for this project..

Comment: 9M records -- no sweat!  :)

You will need a 64-bit OS though to run 64-bit mongod.

Comment: Or use a cloud service like https://mongolab.com and be rid of such nonsensical distinctions.
( full disclosure: i work at MongoLab. :)

Comment: ha, can you hook me up with 4gb fo free?! lol

Comment: i have a question though, is it possible to run a virtual machine with 64 bit ubuntu on an ubuntu box with 64 bit mongodb installed on that? i dont wanna re install my operating system...

Comment: Can't speak to the 64-on-32 VM point — sounds torturous conceptually.
Contrast that with running a pair of 32-bit mongod servers, each being a 2-GB shard comprising half of your 4GB.  That will perform better if your problem will accommodate the sharding.
Alternatively, 4GB is about $1.33/day at MongoLab, fwiw.

Comment: hey thanks for the help! i hit up my local computer lab and begged them until they caved to install a 64 bit version of mongodb so hopefully ill be ok on their system but i appreciate the help!!!